Python Speech-to-text using Whisper model to APK using Kivy , Buildozer
I'm working on speech-to-text using whisper model it runs in my computer but after conversion to APK file it don't. Application creation success and installed in android successfully but not opening. do I need to change anything in "buildozer.spec" file? Please provide guidance or steps.

Try running buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat > my_log.txt. See the documentation.
